# Reading two dimensional array from file

Tags: python, arrays, file

so, I have a file from where I am reading words. I made a editor for the file and have 4 words now in 2 rows. How can I select the word that is in the 1st row and 1st column? Here is the code:

```
username = input("Unesite korisnicko ime\n")
    password = input("Unesite lozinku\n")
    for i in citanjeKorisnika():
        tempKorisnik = i.strip("\n").split("|")
        print(tempKorisnik[0])
        print(tempKorisnik[1])
    if username== tempKorisnik[0] and password==tempKorisnik[1] :
        meniMenadzer()
    elif username == tempKorisnik[0] and password == tempKorisnik[1]:
        meniLekar()
```

Comment: The `csv` module might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to just read the file as follows:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
  res = map( lambda x: x.split(), f.readlines())
print res[0][0]
```

The result would be a 2d-array containing your values, the first row/column being res[0][0].

Answer (score 0):

Read the entire file into memory:

```
rows = []
for i in citanjeKorisnika():
    tempKorisnik = i.strip("\n").split("|")
    rows.append( tempKorisnik )
```

and then `rows[i][j]` will access the j-th column of the i-th row (indexes starting from 0).